# get response from CasperJS in Node.JS

Tags: node.js, casperjs

I have a script which is calling another CasperJS script.

```
    var exec = require('child_process').exec;
    exec("casperjs webCheck/thisWebCheck.js",puts);
```

I need a way to get a response from this script back to the calling script. It just has to be a Boolean value, just yes the webcheck worked, or no the website is down. Then depending on that response I will execute one piece of code or another.

I have searched all through web posts, blog posts and stack exchange for an answer to this and have come up empty.

When I try to use the exit code, it never comes back with what I told it to exit with.

When i use STDOUT and try to validate against it such as

```
thisWebCheck.js

...
if(failed) {
  console.log("failed");
} else {
  console.log("success")
}
```

---

```
Main.js

var puts = function(error, stdout, stderr){
  if (stdout == "failed"){
    doSomething();
  } else if (stdout == "success") {
      doSomethingElse();
  } else {
    console.log(stdout);
  }
};
```

The `main.js` will `console.log()` the stdout but won't validate against the strings.

**TL/DR:** 
I just need some way to communicate between the two scripts. Also, if there is a better way to call the casper file, let me know.

Comment: Where are you declaring `var puts` in relation to the `exec("casperjs ` line? It needs to come before if you are using a function expression. Alternately, try just `function puts` instead of `var puts`

Comment: oh yeah, I coppied the existing code. I would usually use function puts(){...} instead of the other, but i didn't write the initial code.Anyway, I do declare it before I call it, and I used debug statements to make sure it is getting called when it should. but the if/elseif/else isn't evaluating, it's going strait to the else and logging.

Comment: Maybe try `stdout.match('failed')`?